# Clicking "Compensation" causes other navigation links to grow in size

Tags: bug, design, user-experience

In the company about page there are several links at the top.  When I click every link except for "Compensation" the size / font style appears to be the same (consistency):

[image]

However, when I click "Compensation" font size / style seems to change:

[image]

The actual page can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/company

Comment: You mean the other links grow to *compensate*?

Answer (score 2):

The `font-size` for those navigation items are `100%` on all navigation pages, but the Compensation page loads an additional stylesheet called [`company_section_overrides.css`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/company_section_overrides.css?v=ddd0b2e16f5d) which specifies the rule `#content { ... font-size: 14px }`. The outcome is that for the Compensation page only, navigation items display with computed `font-size: 14px` instead of `13px`.

I would personally fix that rule to specify `13px` as well, it makes some body text smaller but leads to an overall more consistent design.